# Using an Interface twice in the same activity

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, interface

Just to let you know, I am quite new to Kotlin, but I have a good experience with Java.
I have two recycler views in an activity, with the same adapter, but different behaviour. In Java, just create an interface in the adapter class and override it using a method setOnItemClick(OnClick onClick), but in Kotlin, things seems to be different.
I saw people overriding the interface in the activity, and that will serve only as one behaviour ...
Any suggestions ?

Update: See Code Below:

Adapter Class :

```
class RoleAdapter(context : Context, list : ArrayList<Role>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RoleAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {

    private var list : ArrayList<Role>? = null
    private var context : Context? = null
    private var listener : OnItemClick? = null

    /**
     * Handle click events on Items.
     * @see RoleAdapter
     */
    interface OnItemClick {

        fun onClick(position : Int)
        fun onHold(position: Int) : Boolean
    }


    /**
     * Return the current list of items displayed
     */
    fun getList() : ArrayList<Role> = list!!

    init {
        this.list = list
        this.context = context
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        return MyViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).
            inflate(R.layout.item_role,parent,false)
        )
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item : Role = list!![position]

        holder.icon.setImageDrawable(Icons.getDrawableIcon(icon = item.getIcon()!!, context = context!!))
        holder.text.text = item.getName()

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            if (listener != null) listener!!.onClick(holder.adapterPosition)
        }

        holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener{
            if (listener != null) listener!!.onHold(holder.adapterPosition)
            return@setOnLongClickListener true

        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return list!!.size
    }

    class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        val icon : ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_icon)
        val text : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_text)
    }

    /**
     * Override the adapter's listener with a new one.
     * @param listener new listener
     */
    fun setListener(listener : OnItemClick){
        this.listener = listener
    }

    /**
     * Add an element to the list displayed by the adapter
     * @param item item to insert
     * @param position insertion position
     */
    fun addItem(item : Role, position: Int){
        list!!.add(item)
        notifyItemInserted(position)
    }

    /**
     * Remove an element from the list displayed by the adapter
     * @param position position of the item to be removed
     */
    fun removeItem(position : Int){
        list!!.removeAt(position)
        notifyItemRemoved(position)
    }
}
```

Activity

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

       
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_game)

        currentPlayersRV = findViewById(R.id.current_players_rv)
        availableRolesRV = findViewById(R.id.roles_rv)

        currentPlayersAdapter = RoleAdapter(context = applicationContext, list = ArrayList<Role>())
        currentPlayersAdapter!!.setListener(INSERT_LISTENER_1)

        currentPlayersRV!!.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(baseContext,3)
        currentPlayersRV!!.adapter = currentPlayersAdapter
        availableRolesAdapter = RoleAdapter(context = applicationContext, list = Role.getRoles(applicationContext))
        availableRolesAdapter!!.setListener(INSERT_LISTENER_2)
        availableRolesRV!!.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(baseContext, 3)
        availableRolesRV!!.adapter = availableRolesAdapter

    }
```

Comment: Interfaces behave the same way in Kotlin and Java, but Kotlin also provides a way to implement an interface by delegating to another object that implements that interface. Doesn't sound like what you're describing, though. We'll have to see an example of what you're talking about.

Comment: I'll update in a minute.

Comment: Updated if you are still here ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've described two ways to implement an interface, and both can be done in either Java or Kotlin.

1. Fragment or Activity class implements the interface itself. Your interface's function signature doesn't provide a way for the adapter to pass itself, so if you use this strategy with multiple adapters, they all have to behave the exact same way. This would only work if both adapters are referencing the same list of data.

```java
// Java
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements RoleAdapter.Listener {

    private List<Something> data;

    // ...

    public void onClick(int position) {
        doSomething(data.get(position));
    }

    public boolean onHold(int position) {
        return doSomethingElse(data.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // ...
        adapter.setListener(this);
        adapter2.setListener(this);
    }
}
```

```kotlin
// Kotlin
class MyActivity: AppCompatActivity(), RoleAdapter.Listener {

    private var data: List<Something>? = null

    // ...

    fun onClick(position : Int) {
        data?.get(position)?.let { doSomething(it) }
    }
 
    fun onHold(position: Int) : Boolean {
        return data?.get(position)?.let { doSomethingElse(it) }
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        // ...
        adapter.listener = this
        adapter2.listener = this
    }
}
```

2. Use distinct anonymous object implementations of the interface for each of the two adapters.

```java
// Java
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private List<Something> data;
    private List<Something> data2;

    private RoleAdapter.Listener adapterListener = new RoleAdapter.Listener() {
        public void onClick(int position) {
            doSomething(data.get(position));
        }

        public boolean onHold(int position) {
            return doSomethingElse(data.get(position));
        }
    };

    private RoleAdapter.Listener adapterListener2 = new RoleAdapter.Listener() {
        public void onClick(int position) {
            doSomething(data2.get(position));
        }

        public boolean onHold(int position) {
            return doSomethingElse(data2.get(position));
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // ...
        adapter.setListener(adapterListener);
        adapter2.setListener(adapterListener2);
    }
}
```

```kotlin
// Kotlin
class MyActivity: AppCompatActivity() {

    private var data: List<Something>? = null
    private var data2: List<Something>? = null

    private val adapterListener = object: RoleAdapter.Listener {
        fun onClick(position : Int) {
            data?.get(position)?.let { doSomething(it) }
        }
 
        fun onHold(position: Int) : Boolean {
            return data?.get(position)?.let { doSomethingElse(it) }
        }
    }

    private val adapterListener2 = object: RoleAdapter.Listener {
        fun onClick(position : Int) {
            data2?.get(position)?.let { doSomething(it) }
        }
 
        fun onHold(position: Int) : Boolean {
            return data2?.get(position)?.let { doSomethingElse(it) }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        // ...
        adapter.listener = adapterListener
        adapter2.listener = adapterListener2
    }
}
```

In my opinion, it is less convoluted if you change the listener function signatures to return actual items instead of item positions. Then the Activity doesn't have to keep track of the data redundantly to the adapter. It would also allow you to use strategy number 1 with multiple adapters and data sets. Example:

```kotlin
// in Adapter class:
interface OnItemClick {
    fun onClick(item: Role)
    fun onHold(item: Role) : Boolean
}

//...

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item : Role = list!![position]

        holder.icon.setImageDrawable(Icons.getDrawableIcon(icon = item.getIcon()!!, context = context!!))
        holder.text.text = item.getName()

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            listener?.onClick(item)
        }

        holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener{
            listener?.onHold(item)
            return@setOnLongClickListener true

        }
    }
```

---

On an unrelated note, Kotlin has properties, so your `getListener` and `setListener` functions are completely redundant. You should remove them and make `listener` a public property.

Also, use of `!!` is almost always a code smell. Use the safe call `?.` if something is possibly null, or make the property non-nullable if it's not supposed to ever be null.

Comment: The second approach is what I meant, Thank you anyway!